# Using .text() to grab the text in a DIV does return the it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm working on a tool that lets the user `<select>` a space type, e.g., office, warehouse, storage, etc., and calculate the kWh usage, kWh cost, fuel usage, fuel cost2, per square foot. The fuel type is natural gas, and the other is everything else.

The value of an option holds various values depending on the space type.  For example, an Office might have:

```html
<option value="21|0.099|25|0.091">Office</option>
```

This is then split into an array using the .split() function, e.g.,

```js
$("#space-type-1 option:selected").val().split("|");
```

I have created a table using `display: table` that has five rows and five columns.

The table header is:

| Space Type | Floor Area | kWh Use | kWh Cost | Fuel Use | Fuel Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Row 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Row 2 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Row 3 |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Total** for the last columns |  |  |  |  |  |

The first column calculates fine, and obviously, the total is correct.

I need to grab the column values from the first row and add them to the column values for the second and third rows. My problem is the values are not displaying property.

For example, kWh Used for row 1 is 9400 and I used toLocaleString() to display this as 9,400. Row 2 has a value of 26000. When I try to add row 2 to row 1, I get 26009, not 34500.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
// Calculate total kWh Usage
var r1 = parseFloat(stVal[0] * fa1);
var r2 = $("#kwh-used-2").text();
var r3 = $("#kwh-used-3").text() > 0
            ? parseFloat($("#kwh-used-3").text())
            : parseFloat(0);
var tkwhUsed = (r1 + r2 + r3);
$("#total-kwh-used").text(tkwhUsed.toLocaleString("en-US", {style:"decimal", maximumFractionDigits:"0"}));


// Calculate total kWH Cost
r1 = parseFloat(stVal[1] * fa1);
r2 = $("#kwh-cost-2").text() > 0
        ? parseFloat($("#kwh-cost-2").text())
        : parseFloat(0);
r3 = $("#kwh-cost-3").text() > 0
        ? parseFloat($("#kwh-cost-3").text())
       : parseFloat(0);
var tkwhCost = (r1 + r2 + r3)
$("#total-kwh-cost").text(tkwhCost);
```

Comment: `parseFloat()` does not handle numbers formatted with thousand separators

Comment: Your code appears to be slightly long for what it does. I am sure it can be shortened and made more concise. If you could provide us with the actual HTML with all of the referenced input and select elements you can help us in coming up with suggestions on how to improve your code.

Comment: @Phil, that solves my problem of getting a 9 when GETing the string "9,400".   I'm formatting the value and using `.text()` to set the `innerHTML` of the`<div>`.  I'll need to remove the comma with `.replace(/,/g, '')` before doing my calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is not very easy to read or follow, due to all the parseFloat(), text() and toLocalString() functions everywhere. The problem is all your program data is hidden in HTML strings, so you have to keep converting types all over the place. A cleaner approach is to keep all your data in JS, then just use HTML to render/display. For example:

```
<option value="option1">Office</option>
```

```
    const options = {
      option1: {area:21, kwhUse:0.099, kwhCost:25.00, fuelCost: 0.091 },
      option2: {....etc}
    }
```

Comment: The cleaner, the better.  I used all the `parseFloat` because the .text() and .val() return strings, and I'm dealing solely with numbers and formatting the decimal from currency numbers using `toLocaleString`.

I can't create global variables inside a blur() function on the floor area, which is what I'm using to activate the calculations.

Comment: The "single source of truth" for all data should be in JS, not HTML. Allow me to explain a bit more. So instead of using .text() to pull data values from HTML, do ```$("#kwh-used-2").text(option1.kwhUse)```. The JS is telling the HTML what the data values are, not the other way around. And the HTMl should only be telling the JS what the user has selected or input.  I believe applying those two rules consistently in your code makes it cleaner and easier to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to add the columns in the tables AFTER I had converted the numerical numbers used in the calculations to strings.  For example, the first row would calculate correctly and display as intended.

When I tried adding the values in the second row to those of the first row, I wasn't converting the string back to a number before trying to add the two values.  This was causing the majority of my problems. Thank you, @Phil, for letting me know that.

I liked and incorporated the suggestion from @PJaoko that streamlined some of the logic. Thank you, PJaoko.

I've recoded the scripting taking into account the suggestions here. I dont foresee additional isues moving forward.  Thanks for everyone's help and sorry for the long and hard to read code.